# Is there a react component event for when url query string parameters change?

Tags: reactjs

Have a react web app with a url by the form of

http://localhost/user?id=123&name=SomeName&team=SomeTeam

Is there an event which fires when either id, name or team parameter is changed?

I know there is componentWillReceiveProps but it appears that it fires only when it is a route parameter i.e.

http://localhost/user/123/

is changed rather than as a query string parameter

Answer (score 5):

You can use `componentDidUpdate` life cycle hook

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
    console.log("Route Updated");
  }
}
```

Comment: You should mention `withRouter` since `location` doesn't just come free with `props`. Also, `location` is an object... I think you mean to compare `this.props.location.pathname`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using react router. You can use location to achieve this behaviour.
Take a look at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location

withRouter(Component)

Your component will get query params in this.props.location.search and when query params change componentWillReceiveProps will fire.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps >> These methods are considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code:

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router v4, you can directly use `withRouter` HOC to get the location prop:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const myComponent = ({ listen }) => {

  listen((location, action) => {
    // location is an object like window.location
    console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state)
  });

  return <div>...</div>;
};

export default withRouter(myComponent);
```

If you are not using react-router, here is a javascript library you can look at https://github.com/ReactTraining/history that you can manage your session history.

You can use `history.listen()` function to detect the route change. Here is a example:

```
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"

const history = createHistory()

// Get the current location.
const location = history.location

// Listen for changes to the current location.
const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
  // location is an object like window.location
  console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state)
})

// Use push, replace, and go to navigate around.
history.push("/home", { some: "state" })

// To stop listening, call the function returned from listen().
unlisten()
```

Comment: getting error - TypeError: listen is not a function

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router v5.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const myComponent = ({ history }) => {

history.listen((location, action) => {
    // location is an object like window.location
    console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state)
 });

 return <div>...</div>;
};

export default withRouter(myComponent);
```